# What HTML That Doesn't Show HTML Tags?

Tags: html, criteo

Few days ago, I visited a site, and for no reason I tried to view its source code. And surprisingly, it doesn't contain regular HTML tags such as `h1`, `h2`, `p`, etc.

it only contains code like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <script>
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  if (window.PerformanceObserver) {
    var observer = new PerformanceObserver(function(list) {
      const entries = list.getEntries();
      for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        // `name` will be either 'first-paint' or 'first-contentful-paint'.
        var metricName = entry.name;
        var time = Math.round(entry.startTime + entry.duration);

        ga('send', {
          hitType: 'timing',
          timingCategory: 'Performance Metrics',
          timingVar: metricName,
          timingValue: time,
        });
      }
    });
    observer.observe({entryTypes: ['paint']});
  }
  </script>

    <!-- Open search -->
      <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="search"
              href="./assets/opensearch-id.xml"/>

  <script>dataLayer = [];</script>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-WJZQSJF');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<link href="***/assets/bundle.f4eb17af99f6bcda6c58794466a0abd3.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WJZQSJF"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

  <div id="main"></div>
  <script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>

  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
      n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
            document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  </script>
  <!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

  <!-- Criteo One Tag Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//*******" async="true"></script>
  <script>window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];</script>
  <!-- End Criteo Code -->

  <script>!function(e){function c(a){if(b[a])return b[a].exports;var d=b[a]={i:a,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[a].call(d.exports,d,d.exports,c),d.l=!0,d.exports}var a=window.webpackJsonp;window.webpackJsonp=function(b,f,n){for(var r,t,o,i=0,u=[];i<b.length;i++)t=b[i],d[t]&&u.push(d[t][0]),d[t]=0;for(r in f)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(f,r)&&(e[r]=f[r]);for(a&&a(b,f,n);u.length;)u.shift()();if(n)for(i=0;i<n.length;i++)o=c(c.s=n[i]);return o};var b={},d={74:0};c.e=function(e){function a(){r.onerror=r.onload=null,clearTimeout(t);var c=d[e];0!==c&&(c&&c[1](new Error("Loading chunk "+e+" failed.")),d[e]=void 0)}var b=d[e];if(0===b)return new Promise(function(e){e()});if(b)return b[2];var f=new Promise(function(c,a){b=d[e]=[c,a]});b[2]=f;var n=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],r=document.createElement("script");r.type="text/javascript",r.charset="utf-8",r.async=!0,r.timeout=12e4,c.nc&&r.setAttribute("nonce",c.nc),r.src=c.p+""+({61:"vendor",62:"bundle",63:"icons",64:"short_url"}[e]||e)+".bundle."+{0:"c38a1529c3b99c325cbb",1:"36418a346d47b7489609",2:"ef74eff3789cd571abc8",3:"40b845bf76f300f55de4",4:"8a6a439aa451d3d927b0",5:"72986b428e8cbd866607",6:"c6c9571f8e2fe5d212bb",7:"aae34ad175b103ef7e4e",8:"242c59a9d553de716c60",9:"ef6bbc1570fb8834ab36",10:"4bbc0a828f9c224773d1",11:"ddb3f50d8864e9408fc1",12:"6c1497f53303248323d7",13:"afeda231b24bbc8194de",14:"a87b72a437d706639baf",15:"09604bb7d99977b19574",16:"2a88b519fe8a5231bed8",17:"8752912c6b561ea445e5",18:"1bc4d82776cf99767789",19:"a2333c0fb5928e5c8294",20:"5b3a12ea7ea8144d0b40",21:"84073184bb3f2047b2a7",22:"20b45cf24e9ba43bfeb9",23:"cd0ea9678da108d1f4ce",24:"cd3c35192890404fa9f8",25:"5eb5420abef187dc2df6",26:"18f747b4b8c098ff19f7",27:"669314a53c5cfe3c73d6",28:"ebcb097c69b716623654",29:"ac9eccdcdb242cc2aef8",30:"5e109d633d36dcbba47f",31:"5a7027b9dfa01f78bf70",32:"61e7dceb5b3a30078d83",33:"4fee29baa1d2816fdae7",34:"cc8761150451212c4a22",35:"b17ad377b0cb1ef37461",36:"66899702ab02bf7a6339",37:"bf88a5c916c22b7dd322",38:"0f8294f2a9a2e2e1ffeb",39:"dc558711f648a8ae4fc6",40:"aa5362b270c5e5c12cb8",41:"53574e3109dc0721b45b",42:"e7d39f00425207d8b5b0",43:"b1cdc408800853db7b1a",44:"90e7fdfc599c75ed6c00",45:"33db36c7330b10227972",46:"830b163b775b656e3a92",47:"03bfb3bbdd79ee0e0442",48:"e0548b8051ef72fb0e4f",49:"a14357c795d7bc1913cd",50:"ed0bec3efe20b2dc2da1",51:"76f7f508111c9d32ea1e",52:"ce6f96656a3b08a5f978",53:"dbce6a5f7c10fc5bda8b",54:"00e18ead99250bf63f01",55:"04d3bb1b65d42a9fdaf4",56:"1a12a992adc0cc13f856",57:"5fe4d3c577315f8f99a2",58:"bcd10412dcbab2259da4",59:"c8db0c00ea4034701abc",60:"d33e9ca4f6d41e01d92c",61:"8ee65c855117c2ea0d78",62:"7d31cc04d88c6681ce75",63:"d2dcedabc8faa5a71473",64:"e66827895350ae2fac63",65:"230b7a8a1670edc8e52c",66:"33b35d4cbdffc7271758",67:"6a55b5d11720b6d975ad",68:"7d28f6e0272beec18917",69:"91c610b55fa27ae0d91c",70:"4c240b9a04ec67a27235",71:"54531e628f75037462bd",72:"f6a6e9ff0ab728eabca1",73:"3d7f47216be8efeca29b"}[e]+".js";var t=setTimeout(a,12e4);return r.onerror=r.onload=a,n.appendChild(r),f},c.m=e,c.c=b,c.d=function(e,a,b){c.o(e,a)||Object.defineProperty(e,a,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:b})},c.n=function(e){var a=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return c.d(a,"a",a),a},c.o=function(e,c){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,c)},c.p="https://cdngarenanow-a.akamaihd.net/shopee/shopee-pcmall-live-id/assets/",c.oe=function(e){throw e}}([]);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://***/vendor.8ee65c855117c2ea0d78.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://***/assets/icons.d2dcedabc8faa5a71473.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://***/assets/bundle.7d31cc04d88c6681ce75.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://***/assets/short_url.e66827895350ae2fac63.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

what programming language / technique is this? it shows all the content on my browser, but the html tags remains invisible. any idea what it is?

Comment: As you can see, there are `script` tags in there. So the whole eventual HTML content is generated by javascript

Comment: As @Johannes said, HTML content is generated by Javascript, you can inspect <div id="main"></div> to see what have inside. Inspect the element allows you to see the generated code  after the DOM.

Comment: Chances are it's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 1):

That's some straight up Javascript you're seeing there, and the code running will be generating all the necessary tags client side (hence why viewing the source doesn't show them).

Try right-clicking on an element and using "Inspect". That should open the browser's dev tools and show the HTML code the Javascript is generating.